# Are eigenvectors returned by R function eigen() wrong?

Tags: r, matrix, eigenvalue, eigenvector, matrix-decomposition

```
#eigen values and vectors
a <- matrix(c(2, -1, -1, 2), 2)

eigen(a)
```

I am trying to find eigenvalues and eigenvectors in R. Function `eigen` works for eigenvalues but there are errors in eigenvectors values. Is there any way to fix that?

[image: code for eigen value and vectors]

Comment: What precisely do you consider to be an error here? Keep in mind that R returns eigenvectors normalized to unit length, and recall that they are also defined up to, in this case, the sign.

Comment: the eigen vectors should be like -1 1 1 -1 like but it comes out to be in decimal while the answers are purely non decimal @JuliusVainora

Comment: Then my comment and @李哲源's answer gives a reason for that: `c(-1, 1) / sqrt(1^2+1^2)` is `c(-0.707, 0.707)`.

Comment: Yeah I got your point @JuliusVainora . I sincerly apologise for delay in response@李哲源

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some paper work tells you

- the eigenvector for eigenvalue 3 is `(-s, s)` for any non-zero real value `s`;
- the eigenvector for eigenvalue 1 is `(t, t)` for any non-zero real value `t`.

Scaling eigenvectors to unit-length gives

```
s = ± sqrt(0.5) = ±0.7071068
t = ± sqrt(0.5) = ±0.7071068
```

Scaling is good because if the matrix is real symmetric, the matrix of eigenvectors is orthonormal, so that its inverse is its transpose. Taking your real symmetric matrix `a` for example:

```
a <- matrix(c(2, -1, -1, 2), 2)
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    2   -1
#[2,]   -1    2

E <- eigen(a)

d <- E[[1]]
#[1] 3 1

u <- E[[2]]
#           [,1]       [,2]
#[1,] -0.7071068 -0.7071068
#[2,]  0.7071068 -0.7071068

u %*% diag(d) %*% solve(u)  ## don't do this stupid computation in practice
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    2   -1
#[2,]   -1    2

u %*% diag(d) %*% t(u)      ## don't do this stupid computation in practice
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    2   -1
#[2,]   -1    2

crossprod(u)
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    0
#[2,]    0    1

tcrossprod(u)
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    0
#[2,]    0    1
```

---

**How to find eigenvectors using textbook method**

The textbook method is to solve the homogenous system: `(A - λI)x = 0` for the Null Space basis. The `NullSpace` function in [my this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43225005/4891738) would be helpful.

```
## your matrix
a <- matrix(c(2, -1, -1, 2), 2)

## knowing that eigenvalues are 3 and 1

## eigenvector for eigenvalue 3
NullSpace(a - diag(3, nrow(a)))
#     [,1]
#[1,]   -1
#[2,]    1

## eigenvector for eigenvalue 1
NullSpace(a - diag(1, nrow(a)))
#     [,1]
#[1,]    1
#[2,]    1
```

As you can see, they are not "normalized". By contrasts, `pracma::nullspace` gives "normalized" eigenvectors, so you get something consistent with the output of `eigen` (up to possible sign flipping):

```
library(pracma)

nullspace(a - diag(3, nrow(a)))
#           [,1]
#[1,] -0.7071068
#[2,]  0.7071068

nullspace(a - diag(1, nrow(a)))
#          [,1]
#[1,] 0.7071068
#[2,] 0.7071068
```

Comment: Yes, I mean the `NullSpace` function. Actually it works fine for finding eigenvectors! But I think that it can be used as solution of linear homogenous systems as well. There is not any similar function or code in `R` to do what `NullSpace`does.